# SASS get a list of CSS rules that contain a variable

Tags: css, sass

I'm looking for a way to parse a scss file and get all the rules that contain a certain variable.

For example in style.scss I have the following code:

```
$var1: '#fff';
#myid { 
    a { 
        color: $var1; 
    }
}
... more random code that does not contain $var1...
#oId { 
    background: $var1;
    .someClass { 
        border: 1px solid $var1; 
    } 
}
```

The resulting list with compiled css rules should be:

```
#myid a
#oId
#oId .someClass
```

Do you have any insights on how to approach this?

Comment: Approach this with what?  Sass does not have such a feature, and CSS most certainly doesn't.

Comment: That's why I'm asking, maybe someone has an idea. Maybe an extension that runs at the same time with the compiler and extracts the resulting rule when encountering the variable.